# What's the meanings of the Routing tables' data in the Mac OS?

Tags: macos, router

I use `netstat` to check the routing tables:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.10.10.1         UGSc           20       16     en0
10.10.10/24        link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
10.10.10.1/32      link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
10.10.10.1         bc:67:1c:40:3:f6   UHLWIir        21       14     en0   1193
10.10.10.104/32    link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
10.10.10.107       a8:6b:ad:6b:c4:a5  UHLWI           0        0     en0    820
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             54  2734893     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
172.16.111/24      link#11            UC              1        0  vmnet1
192.168.220        link#12            UC              1        0  vmnet8
224.0.0/4          link#4             UmCS            2        0     en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI          0        0     en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI          0      784     en0
255.255.255.255/32 link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
```

But I have several questions about this:

1. I do not understand the Flags, Refs, Use and Expire's meaning.
2. You see the `10.10.10.1         bc:67:1c:40:3:f6`, so does this mean the IPv4 can divert to IPv6 address directly?
3. Whats the `link#4` and `link#12` meaning in the *Gateway* field?
4. What's the `Expire` field meaning?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This answer is a quick summary of what the fields mean in the routing table display of `netstat`.  You can find all this information directly from the `netstat`  man page (`man netstat`) or for an excellent primer, see [FreeBSD's Handbook Chapter 31.2 - Gateways and Routes](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html). (Apple's `netstat` is derived from the BSD version).

#### Flags

The flags field shows a collection of information about the route stored as binary choices. Following is extracted directly from the man page.

```
 1       RTF_PROTO1       Protocol specific routing flag #1
 2       RTF_PROTO2       Protocol specific routing flag #2
 3       RTF_PROTO3       Protocol specific routing flag #3
 B       RTF_BLACKHOLE    Just discard packets (during updates)
 b       RTF_BROADCAST    The route represents a broadcast address
 C       RTF_CLONING      Generate new routes on use
 c       RTF_PRCLONING    Protocol-specified generate new routes on use
 D       RTF_DYNAMIC      Created dynamically (by redirect)
 G       RTF_GATEWAY      Destination requires forwarding by intermediary
 H       RTF_HOST         Host entry (net otherwise)
 I       RTF_IFSCOPE      Route is associated with an interface scope
 i       RTF_IFREF        Route is holding a reference to the interface
 L       RTF_LLINFO       Valid protocol to link address translation
 M       RTF_MODIFIED     Modified dynamically (by redirect)
 m       RTF_MULTICAST    The route represents a multicast address
 R       RTF_REJECT       Host or net unreachable
 r       RTF_ROUTER       Host is a default router
 S       RTF_STATIC       Manually added
 U       RTF_UP           Route usable
 W       RTF_WASCLONED    Route was generated as a result of cloning
 X       RTF_XRESOLVE     External daemon translates proto to link address
 Y       RTF_PROXY        Proxying; cloned routes will not be scoped
```

So, looking at the first entry, the flags are UGSc meaning

- `U:  RTF_UP` - Route usable
- `G:  RTF_GATEWAY` - Destination requires forwarding by intermediary
- `S:  RTF_STATIC` - Route added manually
- `c:  RTF_PRCLONING` - Protocol-specified generate new routes on use

#### Refs, Use, & Expire

The `refcnt` field gives the current number of active uses of the route.  Connection oriented protocols normally hold on to a single route for the duration of a connection while connectionless protocols obtain a route while sending to the same destination.  The use field provides a count of the number of packets sent using that route.

Expire is a timeout - a period in which the host doesn't respond to that route.

#### MAC Address and Hardware Devices

The HEX address that you're seeing for the `10.1.0.10.1/32` network (`bc:67:1c:40:3:f6`) is a MAC address, not a IPV6 address.

- A [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is a 48-bit identifier specific to  the *hardware* written in `MM:MM:MM:SS:SS:SS`  The first three bytes (`MM:MM:MM`) identifies (assigned to) the hardware manufacturer and the second three bytes (`SS:SS:SS`) is assigned to the device *by* the manufacturer.
- [An IPV6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) is a 106-bit hexadecimal identifier written as 8 hexidecimal numbers separated by colons:  Example:  `2001:0000:3238:DFE1:0063:0000:0000:FEFB`

The `link#4` and `link#12` refer to the *network device* (i.e. Ethernet Adapter, WiFi Adapter, VPN adapter, etc.).

Comment: so. the gateway can use MAC address to presentation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: The Gateway has IP. MAC. and link

Comment: It needs ALL that information to route packets.  For instance, if the destination subnet is on the LAN it needs the MAC address to forward that info to the switch.  It also needs to know what interface it goes through/to.  This is a [good primer](https://cromwell-intl.com/networking/routing.html) written in lay terms.  You should review that.