# Column explanation for netstat open UDP sockets

Tags: command-line

When I run `netstat -v -a -p udp` to show the open UDP sockets, I get the following output(truncated):

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)      rhiwat  shiwat    pid   epid state  options           gencnt    flags   flags1 usscnt rtncnt fltrs
udp4       0      0  *.53939                *.*                                 786896    9216  20275      0 00180 00000000 0000000000de0741 00000000 04400800      1      0 000003
udp46      0      0  *.56128                *.*                                 786896    9216  20275      0 00180 00000000 0000000000de0740 00000000 00400800      1      0 000003
udp4       0      0  *.*                    *.*                                 786896    9216  78049      0 00080 00000000 0000000000dd0358 00000000 00002800      1      0 000001
```

Is there documentation about what all the columns mean? I am especially interested in the last columns or more specifically: `state`, `options`, `gencnt`, `flags`, `flags1`, `usscnt`, `rtncnt` and `fltrs`.

---

There is one related question, that already answered it about `rhiwat` and `shiwat`:
[What do the "shiwat" and "rhiwat" columns mean in output of netstat -v?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437785/what-do-the-shiwat-and-rhiwat-columns-mean-in-output-of-netstat-v)

> ```
> R-HIWA    Receive buffer high water mark, in bytes.
> S-HIWA    Send buffer high  water mark, in bytes.
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meanings of the Routing tables' data in the Mac OS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336888/whats-the-meanings-of-the-routing-tables-data-in-the-mac-os)

Comment: Did you try the man page?

Comment: I tried the man page on my Mac and the one linked to by my related question. But it could well be that I just missed the information. The question you linked is about the routing table, which in my understanding a completely different output. This is about open sockets, not the routing table.